# Issue with get max id in criteria?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am unable to get max id from table. How can we get max id. My query is as follows,

```
Criteria tot = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(student.class);
tot.add(Restrictions.eq("surveyId",send_Survey));
tot.add(Restrictions.eq("testId", "2" )); // Instead of hard coding as 2 I need to the maximum testId
//tot.addOrder(Order.desc("testId"));
ScrollableResults sc=tot.scroll();
sc.last();
int rowcount=sc.getRowNumber()+1;
System.out.println(" Here is the total count--- "+ rowcount);
```

How can I make a condition in query as maximum testId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like you have some confusion between SQL and ORM approaches. With Criteria API you don't want to specify foreign keys, but entity properties. Given a Student class like this

```
    public class Student {
        private Long id;
        private Set<Survey> surveys;
        private Set<Test> tests;

        ... accessor methods etc

    }
```

Your code would look more like this

```
   tot.createAlias("surveys", "survey");
   tot.createAlias("tests", "test");
   tot.add(Restrictions.eq("survey.id",send_Survey));
```

And a likely subquery like this

```
    DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Test.class);
    subquery.setProjection(Projections.max("id"));

    tot.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("test.id", subquery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use projections.

```
tot.setProjection(Projection.max("testId"));
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I got the following error. "The method max(string) is undefined for the type Projection".

Comment: I tried the following but only one row is getting selected not all rows, tot.setProjection(Projections.max("testId"));

Comment: how can I write this with a DetachedQuery? how can I get max value any suggestions please

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries this has details here